# The max product of input arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the max product of two adjacent elements of a list. I do not know the smallest max I could make. Since the list could include negative numbers, setthing `max=0` is not going to work.

When I tested my code below on `[3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]`, the output was `18` instead of `21`. I am not sure why the program is not testing the product of the last two numbers.Also, when testing only two numbers, `[-1, -2]`, the output was -1000, my initial value for `max`, instead of `2`. Does the loop still work when `i` is in range of `(0,0)`? How should I fix it?

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
    n=len(inputArray)
    product=0
    max=-1000
    for i in range(0,n-2):
        product=inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1]
        if max<=product:
            max=product  

    return max
```

Comment: List or array? Are you using numpy or vanilla python?

Comment: Are you looking for `-float('inf')`?

Comment: You could also use `None` and check `if max is None or max <= product`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the range is one too small: you need

```
for i in range(n-1):
```

A starting value of 0 is the default.

The adjusted loop will go through the last element of the list (not array).

If you prefer, start with the initial product as your maximum:

```
max = inputArray[0] * inputArray[1]
for i in range(1, n-1):
    product = inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1]
    if max <= product:
        max = product
```

Comment: If the loop ends at n-1, would inputArray[i+1]=inputArray[n]? Would that be a null number?

Comment: Yes -- but the loop I posted ends at `n-2`.  Look at the documentation: `range` does *not* include the given "stop" value.  range(1, 4) produces the values (1, 2, 3).

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative solution:

```
lst = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]

res = max(i*j for i, j in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
# 21
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Range is not inclusive of the second param.  range(0,3) will produce a range [0...3) meaning 3 is not inclusive.

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inArr):
    return max([inArr[i]*inArr[i+1] for i in range(0, len(inArr)-1)])
```